# How to remove and then activate an addListener?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to remove a certain event and then activate it.

What happens is as follows:

I have a polygon and with the "mouseover" event opens the InfoWindow, and with the "mouseout" event the InfoWindow closes.

So far so good, the problem is when I'm doing the "drag" event in polygon, "InfoWindow stays in the same place and does not follow the polygon.

So I need to close InfoWindow so the polygon is in the "drag" event, and activate only another time.

How do I do this?

Comment: What does you code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: When you ask a question, people take the time to read it, to think about it, to comment it, and to answer it. What about at least providing feedback to comments or reacting to answers?

Answer (score 0):

The [event namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#event) has everything you need, such as `clearListeners` and `removeListener` methods.

The [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polygon) class has a `dragStart`, a `drag` and a `dragEnd` event.

Therefore you should be able to:

1. Add your listeners
2. Listen for a drag or the start of a drag
3. Close the infowindow / remove your listeners
4. Listen for the end of a drag
5. Add your listeners back

I hope this makes sense.

As a side/personal note and speaking in terms of user experience, I am quite convinced that opening/closing stuff based on mouse movements is not a great idea... but that's just me maybe.